# Django view returning file + flash message

Tags: django, httpresponse, python-3.5

I am returning a pdf file to be downloaded. On success I'd like the success message to be flashed. I want the user to stay at the same page. Ajax wouldn't work as it is file download.

but it seems that the flash messages work only with HttpResponseRedirect objects - and file download does not work with it?
anyway, something like that flashes the message but does not download the file:

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(content=attachment, content_type='application/pdf', redirect_to='/app/')
```

on the contrary, HttpResponse seems to be able to download the file, but the messages don't get flashed.

I'd be grateful for tips :)
Python 3.5, Django 1.10

Comment: FYI: in a case of download file, your flash message will be presented when next page will be loading.

Comment: @SławomirLenart yes that's right, I realized the same. But is there any way to present the message directly on the same page and not when it's loaded again?

Comment: @SeverinSimko: check plenty of topics in the SO about "How to make asynchronous HTTP request ..."